# Are half-elves and half-orcs sterile, or can they interbreed with each other(their respective race) like normal races?

Tags: dnd-5e, half-elf, half-orc

I see that humans can interbreed with either orcs or elves in addition to humans, and the offspring is either a half-elf or half-orc. I realized though, that this offspring is very much like a mule, a combination of two species: a horse and donkey. But the mule is sterile. Does this mean that half-elves *cannot* interbreed with other half-elves, and likewise for half-orcs? ***Or can they?***

Comment: From memory, the answer to this question is setting-specific, so I imagine most answers should specify which settings they're describing.

Comment: related: [Can a Half-Orc have only one Orc grandparent?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163178/can-a-half-orc-have-only-one-orc-grandparent)

Comment: For the record, while mules are sterile, not every hybrid is, in real life. There are even cases where A and B can interbreed and produce viable offspring, and B and C can interbreed and produce viable offspring, but A and C cannot. [Wikipedia’s Species article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species) covers it pretty well as far as I can tell (see about the definition and the “species problem”).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Half-elves and half-orcs are not sterile.

Xanathar's Guide to Everything, p62:

> ***Nonhuman Parents.*** If your character is a half-elf, a half-orc, or a tiefling, you can use one of the tables below to determine the race of each of your parents. [...]

The tables presented below include "one parent was an elf and the other was a human," "one parent was an elf and the other was a half-elf," "one parent was a human and the other was a half-elf," and "both parents were half-elves" (among others). While this may vary by setting, the default laid out in XGtE indicates that half-elves can breed with elves, humans, and other half-elves.

Comment: Which of course implies that humans, elves, orcs, and demons are all technically the same species.

Comment: @GreySage: [Species has no technical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species#The_species_problem), but you're right that they would be the same species *colloquially*. "A simple textbook definition, following Mayr's concept, works well for most multi-celled organisms, but breaks down in several situations:...When hybridisation permits substantial gene flow between species.[79]"

Comment: "Allopatric speciation" is a *mechanism* for specialization, not a definition. And Darwin said "No one definition (of species) has as yet satisfied all naturalists". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_concept#From_Darwin_to_Mayr suggests that he assumed it would be obvious, but never actually defined it.  So... what do you think is the technical definition?

Comment: I know in the Kingdom of Bloodstone, the city Palischuk is populated with majority half-orcs and most of them are clearly stated to be 3rd or 4th generation, meaning half-orcs  breed true with other half-orcs in Faerun.

Comment: no mention of aasimar?! SPECICISTS!

Comment: Also, since this doesn't specify setting...in Eberron there's an _entire culture_ made up of half-elves. They call themselves Khorovar, and the vast bulk of them are half-elves with half-elven parents. There are so many of them that 2 of the Dragonmarked Houses are Half-elven (Lyrandar and Medani)

Comment: As the counter-example, in the Dark Sun setting, muls (half-dwarves, half-human) *are* explicitly sterile, both with themselves and with either parent race.